# Display Property table-cell or inline-block

Tags: html, css, display

I have a class by this name →

```
.header-menu
```

which has been defined as →

```
.header-menu {
   display: table-cell;
}
```

Now comes the question →
what should I use for display property of →

```
.header-menu ul li
```

to arrange those elements inline.

I tried these →

```
   display: inline-block        
    display: table-cell
    display: inline
```

and both are fine, but semantically and authentically and in the sense of good practice which is the correct one keeping in mind the fact that base class is defined as →

```
.header-menu {display: table-cell}
```

Truth be told that both are working fine, but I want to know the best coding practice for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS styles are not semantic so you don't have to worry about that. It's more about what support you want. `inline-block` and `table-cell` are both supported up to 98% of browsers.

> what should I use for display property of to arrange those elements inline.

Why not just use `display: inline` ?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question a little bit above.

Comment: If inline is how you want the content to flow inside your table-cell then it's perfectly fine. Same goes for inline-block, block, table-cell. There's no correlation (semantically) when say using table on a parent element and table-cell on it's child. The reason you'd want to do that is because you want to style the content as a table. It makes no difference to the crawlers.